# Expires header and performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, http, iis

OK, I'm having aplay with expires headers in IIS6 on our development server and I don't really get it!

So if I don't add an expires header to a file I get the following request/response when viewed with firebug:

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __utma=222382046.267771103.1330592028.1337002926.1340787333.122; __utmz=222382046.1330592028.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=76038230.629470783.1340728034.1340728034.1340786921.2; __utmz=76038230.1340728034.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); timeOutCookie=Wed%20Jun%2027%202012%2011%3A17%3A22%20GMT+0100%20%28GMT%20Daylight%20Time%29; __utmb=76038230.26.10.1340786921; __utmb=222382046.5.10.1340787333; ASP.NET_SessionId=yhib5kyxf1m5azuhoogrstt5; __utmc=76038230; Travel2=ECC62DC4F9C36A41F3BCF0C54F96D877FEA32D4867DB1A3A97D0C6A3BE79EE98517B9B1A4E24289C863D86A2A4A846EA1FF4BF3822E8B6CBF872E25DD1ADF306F724EE1500AA71E28CFCD02476748163929B73856C505E50D185C05E6322488F
Host    site
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://site/Agents/Flights/FlightSearch.aspx?
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  17864
Content-Type    application/x-javascript
Date    Wed, 27 Jun 2012 09:21:07 GMT
Etag    "0de7d7f192dcd1:a07d"
Last-Modified   Tue, 08 May 2012 12:53:00 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Now if I press f5 now, the system retrieves the file from the client cache, cool!

Now if I add the expires header and press ctrl f5 I get a slightly different request/response:

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __utma=222382046.267771103.1330592028.1337002926.1340787333.122; __utmz=222382046.1330592028.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=76038230.629470783.1340728034.1340728034.1340786921.2; __utmz=76038230.1340728034.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); timeOutCookie=Wed%20Jun%2027%202012%2011%3A21%3A11%20GMT+0100%20%28GMT%20Daylight%20Time%29; __utmb=76038230.27.10.1340786921; __utmb=222382046.5.10.1340787333; ASP.NET_SessionId=yhib5kyxf1m5azuhoogrstt5; __utmc=76038230; Travel2=ECC62DC4F9C36A41F3BCF0C54F96D877FEA32D4867DB1A3A97D0C6A3BE79EE98517B9B1A4E24289C863D86A2A4A846EA1FF4BF3822E8B6CBF872E25DD1ADF306F724EE1500AA71E28CFCD02476748163929B73856C505E50D185C05E6322488F
Host    site
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://site/Agents/Flights/FlightSearch.aspx?
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   max-age=86400
Content-Length  17864
Content-Type    application/x-javascript
Date    Wed, 27 Jun 2012 09:24:41 GMT
Etag    "0de7d7f192dcd1:a082"
Last-Modified   Tue, 08 May 2012 12:53:00 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Brilliant I've now got a max age in the cache control. Now what's confusing me is this as far as I can tell has now practical difference in how the site performs in terms of downloads. If I press f5 it gets it from the cache, if I press control f5 it gets it from the server with a HTTP 200.

So how does this improve performance? How do you get a HTTP 304 instead of a http 200? I just don't get what this practically archives?

any help would be good thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `Expires` or `max-age` explicitly, you are telling the client that it will be safe to cache the response for that much time. The client will happily get it from cache, it will *not* touch your server, there will be no 304. Unless you do Ctrl+F5, which forces the browser to do a full request anew, resulting in 200.

Now what if you don’t set `Expires` nor `max-age`? This just means that the client will [pick an expiration time *by itself*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.2.2), heuristically. Your response is still cached, only the browser has to guess for how long.

So, `Expires`/`max-age` are useful in two cases.

- If you want to *recommend* caching for a specific period of time—longer than a browser would guess. This is often done with versioned static content, which never changes, so expiration time is set on the order of years.
- If you want to *prevent* caching, in which case you set `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Expires` in the past (some versions of IE will ignore `no-cache`).

Conditional requests, 304 and all that, only come to play after the content has *already expired*. To revalidate it, the client might do a conditional `GET`, which, depending on your server setup, may or may not result in 304.

Answer (score 0):

The performance improvements come from making fewer HTTP requests. When a browser is parsing a page and sees it has to request a CSS file, if it's already got a copy of it in it's cache with a `max-age=31536000`, it knows it's cached copy of the file is good for 1 year and doesn't have to make the HTTP request to fetch the file.

Less round trips to the server should result in a faster loading page, and a better experience for users.